# Inheriting properties with accessibility modifier in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, properties

I tried to inherit interface, and make some of the automatically generated set property as private. This is an example.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public interface A 
    {
        int X {get; set;}
    }
    public interface B : A
    {
        int Y {get; set;}
    }

    public class C : A
    {
        public int X {get; private set;}
    }
```

When I tried to compile it. I got an error `'MyClass.C' does not implement interface member 'MyClass.A.X.set'. 'MyClass.C.X.set' is not public.`.

I tried with `private set;` in `iterface A`, but I got this error again : `'MyClass.A.X.set': accessibility modifiers may not be used on accessors in an interface`.

Is this accessibility modifier not allowed in C#?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> I tried with private set; in iterface A, but I got this error again

If your interface only requires that a property should be retrievable, you define it as:

```
public interface A 
{
    int X {get;}  // Leave off set entirely
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The declaration of an interface defines the public set of members that the implementing type must have. So, if `C` implements `A`, it must have a public member for each member defined by the interface.

`A` defines that any implementing type must have a public property `X` with a public getter and a public setter. `C` does not meet this requirement.

Comment: Public member is not the only option. Explicit interface implementation is the other one.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of an interface as the minimum functionality that your class must implement. If the interface specifies that a property exposes a `get` and a `set` clause, then you must implement a public `get` and `set` clause in your class, because only public methods and properties can implicitly implement interfaces.

You can simply leave out the `set` keyword in the interface property definition if you don't want to expose a public mutator. Then you can make the implementation mutator either public or private.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not allowed.  Remember, code which is using an instance of `class C` *must* be able to treat it as an `interface A`, which means that the contract is a public getter and setter for property X.

This applies to class inheritance as well as interface inheritance -- you must follow the contract of the type you are derived from.

If the intent of the code is that property X should not have a public setter, then the interface should be defined with just the `{ get; }`

Answer (score 0):

I believe interface members must be public if the interface itself is public. Your implementation of the property is faulty because of that.

Comment: Members which implicitly implement interface members must be public *regardless* of the accessibility domain of the interface itself.